# How to reassign an element of a dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm trying to change a variable used as an element of a list after I've defined the variable... Hopefully the code will explain my problem better than I can:

```
i = 0
friend = "jake"

stuff = [friend]
dialogue = ["talk to %s please" %(stuff[0])]

while i < 2:
    print (dialogue)
    friend = "paul"
    print ("")
    i+=1
```

as it stands the program prints:

```
talk to jake please

talk to jake please
```

but I want it to print:

```
talk to jake please

talk to paul please
```

Thanks in advance for your help

**EDIT**

I've realised this example ^ is an over simplification of my problem, so I've written another basic program which better describes my problem and have put it on another question to prevent this one becoming too convaluded

Comment: I'd need to keep the structure similar as this is just a simplification of the problem in the program im working on, where I can't just rewrite the 
    stuff = [friend] 
or 
    dialogue = dialogue = ["talk to %s please" %(stuff[0])]
I just need a way to be able to just redefine the friend variable more times down the page to result in the dialogue output to change

Answer (score 0):

Change `friend = "paul"` to `stuff[0] = "paul"`

Alternatively, you could keep `friend = "paul"` but put `stuff = [friend]` again on the line below it.

After either of those, you would need to put the `dialogue = ["talk to %s please" %(stuff[0])]` line again.

If you want to know why your way doesn't work, please ask in the commends. Tell me if this works!

P.S. There are many better ways to do the thing your trying to do. I suggest you learn about iteration, lists, and for loops.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your simplified problem, it seems as if you have different variables in the `stuff` list that mean different things.

A more appropriate data-structure for that kind of thing (especially when you will be modifying things) is a **`dictionary`**.

So, you could define `stuff` as:

```
stuff = {"friend": "jake"}
```

and then you could do things like:

```
print("talk to %s please" % stuff["friend"] )
#talk to jake please
```

and also modify the friend attribute much easier than a `list` by doing:

```
stuff["friend"] = "paul"
```

making the output of the snippet two above now:

```
talk to paul please
```

Comment: Dictionaries might actually make a lot of sense for what im trying to do in both this example and in my program, I'll try and convert my lists (that would benefit) into dicts and i'll let you know if that works, thanks!